# Is Helvetica a browser base font?

Tags: fonts

Can anyone tell me whether Helvetica is a browser base font? If so, it is not loading in my PS CS 4.

Where can I download it from?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, Helvetica is not a "base font".

The best definition of "bast font" is probably Microsoft's [Core Fonts for the web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web), and Helvetica's not there.

If you want Helvetica, you either have to get a Mac (it's one of the default fonts on mac OS X), or [buy it from Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/526/helvetica-family.html) (the company that owns it).

Answer (score 11):

This is actually a comment to Mark Ransom but it grew to big to be a comment.

Not only is there a a free URW++ clone of Helvetica, financed by GNU as part of the GhostScript project, it is one of the nicest looking Helvetica replacemants out there: URW++ Nimbus Sans. Unfortunately, for a lot of uses, it is a PS Type 1 font.

The FreeSans font (in the openfont file format), also from the GNU project, is based on Nimbus Sans. It comes with most Linux distributions. It is much better looking then Arial (especially in print or on screen when using computer systems that don't support Micro Softs (patented) font aliasing technology) and perhaps even Helvetica, and support lots of Unicode glyphs, but it is not metric compatible with Helvetica, like Arial.

There is a free (in every sense of the word) Arial substitute font, named Liberation Sans, that is metric compatible with Arial and hence Helvetica, but it doesn't really look like Helvetica and not much like Arial either.

Neither Nimbus, Arial, Liberation Sans or FreeSans support all the style variations of Helvetica (and even less all the variations of Helvetica Neue, a font that come bundled with OS X). Nimbus is the most Helvetica compatible of the free fonts mentioned, as it support all the variations that came with Helvetica in a PostScript 2 printer and with older Mac OS. But most modern day wordprocessors (and certainly not web-browsers) can't make use of all the variations, not even those that support PS Type 1 fonts.

Nimbus and FreeSans is under the "GPL with a font exception" license, which allow embedding in documents. Most commercial fonts don't allow embedding without a heavy license fee. Embedding is not allowed for any fonts that come with Windows and OS X, neither for almost all of the fonts bundled with other MS or Apple software, nor do they allow the fonts to be shipped with the digital document to a print shop. With most commercial fonts, the print shop must own a license for the font to print the document, this is especially difficult with Windows fonts, since most (all?) Micro Soft fonts licenses don't allow for use outside MS Windows (the MS Web Core fonts for the Web is no good for print, not metric compatible with newer font versions and support a very limited set of glyphs), so they must also use MS Windows based software everywhere in the preprint chain.

Comment: What is the problem with the file format? I mean, I never understood. Can't you just convert from Type 1 to TTF? I did such a thing a long time ago and it just worked. It was a school project however.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this was very informative!

Answer (score 6):

Helvetica is a standard system font on Macs only.

What you can do however is specify Helvetica in a CSS font declaration, but also make sure that you include fallback fonts for Windows users.

e.g.

```
body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Comment: It's probably best to put Helvetica before Arial in that example, as often both fonts are installed on a Mac.

Comment: and don't forget the `sans-serif` at the end of that list.

Comment: Verdana is a wide sans-serif, while Arial and Helvetica are narrow. Columns of text and vertical flow will be dramatically different than what you may intend if you design with that font stack. Try this for a reference: http://safalra.com/web-design/typography/web-safe-fonts-myth/

Comment: The problem is if a windows user has helvetica installed, it will usually render like crap. So don't put it in front of Arial. Just use sans-serif

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a Windows PC, and don't want to purchase Helvetica, Arial is somewhat similar to Helvetica (puts on flame retardant suit).

Microsoft Sans Serif, with its horizontal and vertical terminals (cuts), is more Helvetica-like than Arial is, but only if you don't need italics; Microsoft Sans Serif's italics have far too much slope.

Comment: Just don't look too hard, and you'll be okay. And don't argue the point with designers. The slanted terminals drive them crazy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a collection of standard Postscript fonts available from URW++ under the GPL license; I believe this includes a clone of Helvetica, although it might not go by that name.

Answer (score 0):

To maximise your chances of browser running Helvetica you can set good fallback stack. ( I am assuming here you actually mean Helvetica neue which is more often used in designs ).

```
body {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

stollen from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/better-helvetica/

As said before, Helvetica is base font on mac, but not often used on pcs. That means it's a bit more than 10% of people (desktop speaking) that will have it working out of box.

If you want your website to display everywhere this same you probably want to buy the font. You can buy Helvetica on a lot of websites. Prices vary but for small web usage, you are looking at 30 pounds minimum for one type variation ( 40 dollars ).

Another alternative is to use different font. Open sans in google fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans is often recommended although, in my opinion, it's not really a replacement.

There's a lot of articles that are listing similar fonts to Helvetica, some of them are free. Good starting point could be this article:

https://pangrampangram.com/blogs/journal/helvetica-alternatives